# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket on Travis CI

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

I'm in the process of implementing automation testing on Travis CI.
Below are the `docker-compose.yml` and `.travis.yml` files.

**.travis.yml**

```
dist: trusty
language: php
sudo: required
group: edge

php:
  - '5.6'
  - '7.1'

services:
  - docker
  - mysql

git:
  quiet: true

before_install:
  - sudo chmod +x docker-compose.yml

before_script:

script:
  - docker-compose up -d
  - docker exec -i travistest_db_1  mysql -uwordpress -pwordpress wordpress < wordpress.sql
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ~/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ~/wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8004:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8011:80"

volumes:
  db_data:
```

When I try to fire an SQL query, it throws this error:

`mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer`

I've been trying to debug this for hours but no luck yet, has anyonce faced this issue and managed to fix this?

Is there an alternative to import the SQL file?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the MySQL database have not been initialized yet when the command :

```
docker exec -i travistest_db_1 mysql -uwordpress -pwordpress wordpress < wordpress.sql
```

is run. You need to temporize this command, and there are many ways to do this :

- wait until `[Note] mysqld: ready for connections.` appears in `travistest_db_1` logs
- wait until the following command :

  ```
  docker inspect -f \
      '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}:3306' \
      travistest_db_1
  ```

  returns a `0` exit status (meaning that port 3306 is open and allows connections)
- use a [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) in your `docker-compose.yml` file for your `db` service (you can configure parameters according to your needs) :

  ```
  healthcheck:
    test: "cat /proc/net/tcp /proc/net/tcp6 | grep ':0CEA'"
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 5
  ```

  and wait until :

  ```
  docker inspect -f '{{.State.Health.Status}}' \
      travistest_db_1
  ```

  returns `healthy`. The `cat /proc/net/tcp /proc/net/tcp6 | grep ':0CEA'` command used in the healthcheck returns `0` if port `:0CEA` (`:3306` in hex) is bound on IPv4 or IPv6 (meaning that MySQL is ready to accept connections). Since there is no tool like `curl` or `wget` in `mysql:5.7` image, this seems to be the only command to check if port is open

Whatever solution you choose, you have to add a command between `docker-compose up` and `docker exec` for busy waiting, like the following for the 3rd solution with `healthcheck` (solution I prefer) :

```
while [ "$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Health.Status}}' travistest_db_1)" != "healthy" ];
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @norbjd, I'm not that of a pro with linux commands, can you help me out with that?

Comment: @SiddharthThevaril I have just edited my answer with the different solutions (I'd rather use the 3rd) and the command for waiting.